# How can I click() this image?

Tags: javascript, jquery, extjs5

I want to be able to fire an event click to the image. like image.click();

Here's my element information:

```
 <img class="image" role="button" alt="" src="picture.png">
```

Comment: Format your image markup like this: <a href=”URL of destination site page”> <img class="image" role="button" alt="" src="picture.png"></a>

Comment: What would you like to happen after you click it?

Comment: it is not a link that once click will open a webpage or whatever. it is once clicked, suppose to remove that picture from that area.

Comment: You can use the `onclick` JavaScript listener to trigger this removal when the click event happens.

Answer (score 3):

use below code `.` is use for [class](https://api.jquery.com/class-selector/) selector

```
  $('.image').on('click',function(){
     $(this).remove(); // as mention by @v kind this code remove image after click.
  });
```

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  
   $('.image').on('click',function(){
      
      alert("clicked");
      $(this).remove();
     
   });
   
     $('.image').click(function(){
        alert("clicked Again");
     });

     $('.image').trigger('click'); // use trigger to fire click event on image
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<img class="image" role="button" alt="" src="https://www.google.co.in/images/srpr/logo11w.png">
```

Comment: that picture once clicked is suppose to remove that picture, the code above doesn't do it.

Comment: How do you know if he is using jQuery ?

Comment: @xsami question taged in jquery .

Comment: @VKid  you don't mention in question that you want to remove image after click

Comment: I want to trigger a click event to that image.

Comment: @VKid why do you want a trigger?

Comment: @VKid see i update my code see snippet . when you click image it gives alert then image is removed

Comment: @VKid can you explain what you mean by click ? as my example fires an click event when you click on image ?

Comment: $('.image').click(); I want to actually code the part where you actually click it first.

Comment: seee my updated snippet . may be help . you want to trigger image click event on any other  event fire ? here very confusing what you want to ask ?

Comment: I don't want to have to manually click the image myself, I want to do it from the console and it will click it by itself.

Answer (score 2):

there is no need for jQuery here, use plain JS

```
document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0].addEventListener("click", function() {
    alert("a");
});
```

and just to click it `document.getElementsByClassName('image')[0].click();`

Answer (score 1):

Try this, but there are many options:

```
<img class="image" role="button" alt="" src="picture.png" onclick="You clicked me">
```

or you can also do:

```
<a href="#"><img class="image" role="button" alt="" src="picture.png"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do something like

```
<img class="image" role="button" alt="" src="picture.png" onclick='DoSomething()'>
```

or you can use a hyperlink or jquery and use the class selector

```
$('.image').on('click', function(){
   $(this).remove(); // this is to remove the image if you want to
});
```

Comment: I really don't want to remove it, I want to programmatically click that image.

Comment: programmatically click it?

Comment: That is because, when I manually click it, it suppose to do it's thing and dissappear.

Comment: @Sushil yes, click it

Comment: yeah. as per your requirement, one of these answers should serve your purpose or you're not framing your question correctly

Answer (score 0):

Apply on click on the image [0]

```
document.images[0].onclick = function() { 
  console.log("i am clicked");
}

<img class="image" role="button" alt="" src="picture.png">
```